# I cant Instantiate a particle system for the duration of a subroutine

Tags: unity, c#, particles

[image]I have a sub routine that lowers the timescale to 0.3 for 2 seconds. while in those two seconds i would like to spawn a trail of particles that follow the player.

I can get the particles working if I attach them to the player in the editor but I'm having trouble spawning them at the start of the time slow down.
The slow down subroutine works fine its just the particles that i cant spawn.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

```
public GameObject particles;
public Transform playerParticles;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    slowDownActivateNoise = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (hasCollided)
    {
        if (!activated)
        {
            StartCoroutine("SlowDownActive");
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerator SlowDownActive()
{

    Debug.Log("subroutine Start");
    activated = true;
    Instantiate(particles, playerParticles.position, playerParticles.rotation);

    Time.timeScale = 0.3f;
    GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;
    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    hasCollided = false;
    activated = false;
    Debug.Log("subroutine end");

}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should correctly spawn the `particles` object, though it looks like you'll probably want to capture a reference to the spawned instance so that you can eg. parent it to the player object, and destroy it when the time is up. Can you show us how you've configured this script in the inspector, how your `particles` object is set up, and any errors you're seeing in the console?

Comment: Hi, I edited the post with an image of my editor. I created an empty gameObject as a child of the player and passed it in as a transform in the script.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say that I'm not getting any errors in the console